# Least Positive integer satisfying the condition $x^{2} -4x > \cot^{-1}x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What is the least positive integer satisfying the condition:  $$x^{2} -4x > \cot^{-1} (x)$$

Graphically entering the value $y=x^{2} -4x$ and $y= \cot^{-1}(x)$, I concluded that the answer is $x=5$ as it satisfies the condition of a positive integer, but I would like to solve this question using a mathematical equation if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$ f(x)=x^2-4x-\cot^{-1}x. $$
Note that
$$ f'(x)=2x-4+\frac{1}{x^2+1}>0 $$
implies $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\ge 2$. Clearly when $x=1,2,3,4$, the inequality does not hold since the LHS is non-positive. When $x=5$, the inequality holds. Thus $x=5$ is the smallest integer satisfying the inequality.

Comment: xpaul's answer might well be better than mine; it depends on the *intent* of the questioner.  If the question is for a pre-calculus class, he probably intended that you strive for the insight in my answer.  If the question is for a calculus class, xpaul's answer is probably preferable.

Comment: Can this be found using the concept tan x>x>sin x

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi Re my previous comment, I suspect that the *intended* answer is either xpaul's answer or mine.

Comment: can we use the concept $cot^{-1 } x>\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi, I doubt.

Answer (score 3):

$x \in \mathbb{Z^+} \Rightarrow cot^{-1} x > 0.\;\;$ 5 is the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $x^2 - 4x > 0.$

Comment: I know that the condition of x is x>4 and x<0 but still can it be derived mathematically if possible